# Inheriting from super class to subclasses in Python

Tags: python, oop

I have a super class which has some class attributes like:

```
class Config(object):    
    LENGTH = 1
    BREADTH = 3
```

Now ,I have created a subclass which will override the parent class attributes.

```
 class Sub1(Config):
     def __init__():
        self.LENGTH = 200
        self.BREADTH = 100
        self.AREA = self.LENGTH * self.BREADTH
```

Now I need to write another subclass which will overwrite the values of the first sub class. Here, shall I inherit from the parent class Config or I can overwrite the values in the subclass itself and change it.

```
class Sub2(Sub1):
   self.AREA_UPDATED = self.AREA + 20
```

This is not working.

```
class Sub2(Config):
    self.LENGTH = "efg"
    self.BREADTH = 100
    self.AREA = self.LENGTH * self.BREADTH
    self.AREA_UPDATED = self.AREA + 20
```

This works. What am I doing conceptually wrong, is it that the parent class can be inherited only? Kindly advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `self` in the `class` scope. You should just use the variable name simply like this:

```
class Sub2(Config):
    LENGTH = "efg"
    BREADTH = 100
    AREA = LENGTH * BREADTH
    AREA_UPDATED = AREA + 20
```

Because this way you will overwrite the class attributes not just the instance attributes as you did it in the `__init__`.

Inheriting from `Sub1` you can do the same:

```
class Sub1(Config):
    LENGTH = 200
    BREADTH = 100
    AREA = LENGTH * BREADTH 

class Sub2(Sub1):
    AREA_UPDATED = Sub1.AREA + 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
class Sub2(Sub1):
   self.AREA_UPDATED = self.AREA + 20
```

to

```
class Sub2(Sub1):
  def __init__(self):
     self.AREA_UPDATED = self.AREA + 20
```

Comment: You should fix the `__init__` like this: `def __init__(self):`. And on the class level you can't use `self`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't you use the breadth and width in the **init** to instantiate an object correctly?
I mean just like this:

```
class Config(object):
   def __init__(self, width, breadth):
       self.width = width
       self.breadth = breadth
       self.area = width*breadth
```

taking the config as a superclass ( you could also use it as abstract base class, in which case my solution would be wrong).

And afterwards just properly let Sub1 inherit from Config like this:

```
class Sub1(Config):
  def __init__(self,width,breadth):
      Config.__init__(self,width,breadth)
      self.area = width * breadth
```

for sub2 you could obviously do the same. If you would want to know the updated area, you could just use setters for the attributes the class has.